# Group effects where there is a single group

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

Suppose I have a table of subjects and measurements as follows

```
subject measurement
s1        1
s1        2
s1        3
s1        4
s1        5
s1        6
s1        7
s1        8
s1        9
s1       10
s2       10
```

Now it is unlikely that the true value of s2 is 10 as observed. It is much more likely to be closer to the mean of the s1 measurements. How do I discover the true value?

I've discovered that if I construct the following table:

```
group subject measurement
g1  s1  1
g1  s1  2
g1  s1  3
g1  s1  4
g1  s1  5
g1  s1  6
g1  s1  7
g1  s1  8
g1  s1  9
g1  s1  10
g1  s2  10
g2  s1  1
g2  s1  2
g2  s1  3
g2  s1  4
g2  s1  5
g2  s1  6
g2  s1  7
g2  s1  8
g2  s1  9
g2  s1  10
g2  s2  10
```

and run the following R command

```
 fit = lmer(measurement ~ 1 + (subject|group))
```

I get a plausible answer. Is it correct? Is there a better way? In R? I had to double the table up to coerce R to solve the problem as it doesn't seem to like a single group.

Comment: What do you mean by "true value" of an individual measurement?

Comment: @MichaelMayer Suppose that there were many more measurements made of s2, and each measurement is subject to error as is evident with s1, then the mean of those would be closer to the true value.

Comment: Unless you know exactly what the software is doing, it is rarely the case that creating bogus data produces any valid result. It definitely is invalid here. You need to step back and think about your assumptions. The key one appears to be that there is no variability between subjects: that all variability should be attributed to measurement error alone. Is there any basis to support that assumption? If not, you have to stop. If there is, you can test the second subject's value by erecting a *prediction interval* (search our site) based on the first subject's measurements.